# Como fazer left join com multiplas condições usando a classe DBIx

Tags: mysql, query, orm, perl

Tenho a seguinte consulta:

```
SELECT *
FROM endereco e
LEFT JOIN favorite f ON f.end_id = e.end_id AND f.user_id = '123'
ORDER BY 
  CASE WHEN f.end_id IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, -- ordena por favoritos primeiro
  e.name -- ordena pelo nome
```

Nessa consulta ele possui um left join com a condição do user. Preciso fazer a mesma coisa usando o DBIx no Perl.
No Model de Endereco possuo:

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "favorite",
  "Models::Result::Favorite",
  sub {
    my $args = shift;
    return {
      "$args->{foreign_alias}.end_id" => { -ident => "$args->{self_alias}.end_id" },
      "$args->{foreign_alias}.user_id" => { '=',  "$args->{self_alias}.user_id" },
    };
  },
  { cascade_copy => 0, cascade_delete => 0 },
);
```

E pra fazer a query ja tentei usar o prefetch só e nao funcionou, exemplo:

```
  prefetch => ['favorite'],
```

A condição de user não é aplicada. Como posso fazer?

Answer (score -2):

Para adicionar a condição do usuário na cláusula **LEFT JOIN** usando o **DBIx** no **Perl**, você precisa usar a opção **join_type** do método **has_many**. Esta opção permite que você especifique o tipo de junção que será usada na cláusula **JOIN** gerada pelo **DBIx**.

Você pode atualizar o código do **Model de Endereco** para adicionar a opção **join_type** e especificar a condição do usuário como uma cláusula **AND** na junção. Por **exemplo**:

```
__PACKAGE__->has_many(
  "favorite",
  "Models::Result::Favorite",
  sub {
    my $args = shift;
    return {
      "$args->{foreign_alias}.end_id" => { -ident => "$args->{self_alias}.end_id" },
    };
  },
  {
    cascade_copy => 0,
    cascade_delete => 0,
    join_type => 'LEFT JOIN',
    on => sub {
      my $on = shift;
      $on->and(
        { 'favorite.user_id' => { '=', \'123' } },
        { 'favorite.end_id' => { '=', \"me.end_id" } },
      );
    },
  },
);
```

Neste **exemplo**, adicionamos a opção **join_type** com o valor '**LEFT JOIN**' para especificar o tipo de junção. Também adicionamos a opção on com uma subrotina que adiciona a condição do usuário como uma cláusula **AND** na junção. A **condição** do usuário é definida usando uma **referência** a uma **string literal**, '**123**', para evitar que o valor seja citado incorretamente na consulta gerada.

Com essas atualizações, o **DBIx** deve gerar uma cláusula **LEFT JOIN** com a condição do usuário na sua consulta. Note que neste **exemplo**, estamos especificando um valor fixo para o usuário ('**123**'). **Se você quiser usar um valor dinâmico** para o usuário, pode modificar a subrotina on para aceitar um parâmetro que contenha o valor do usuário a ser usado na consulta.

Answer (score -4):

Eu penso que esta forma pode ajudar. Eu usei a cláusula de junção condicional 'ON'
para adicionar a condição do usuário à consulta como [nesta discusão](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=1206286).

Para traduzir para DBIx::Class, especifiquei a tabela ('favorite') e a condição de junção com `join` e `-and`. A cláusula `join` para especificar a tabela e a `-and` para especificar as condições da junção. como [explicado aqui](https://metacpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/view/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Joining.pod)

Além disso, a cláusula `order_by` que usei para especificar a ordem de classificação, que é a mesma da consulta que mostraste. A expressão `(CASE WHEN favorite.end_id IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)` na cláusula `order_by` é equivalente à cláusula `CASE` da consulta que mostraste.

Por fim, o método `search` que [cabulei aqui](https://metacpan.org/dist/DBIx-Class/view/lib/DBIx/Class/Manual/Cookbook.pod) para executar a consulta.

```
my $endereco_rs = $schema->resultset('Endereco')->search(
  undef,
  {
    join => {
      'favorite' => {
        '-and' => [
          { 'favorite.end_id' => { -ident => 'me.end_id' } },
          { 'favorite.user_id' => '123' },
        ],
      },
    },
    order_by => [
      { '-asc' => 'CASE WHEN favorite.end_id IS NOT NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END' },
      { '-asc' => 'me.name' },
    ],
  }
);
```

Comment: Não funcionou, ele retornou o erro: No such relationship '-and' on Favorite

Comment: Eu editei o codigo. Poderia verificar agora? Eu usei o método 'search_related' e vi o erro que tinha cometido no -and.